# Show that $f_n \rightarrow f$ almost surely with respect to $\mu$ .

Tags: probability-theory, solution-verification

Let $(X, \mathcal{E}, \mu)$ be a measure space and let $f, f_1, f_2, f_3$ be functions from $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{E})$ such that $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $\mu$-measure. Assume further than the sequence $(f_n)$ is increasing such that
$$f_1 \leq f_2 \leq f_3 \leq \dots \quad \mu \text{-almost surely}$$
Then I have to argue that $f_n \rightarrow f$ $\mu$-almost surely.

My attempt:

As $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $\mu$-measure there exists an increasing sequence $(n_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $f_{n_k} \rightarrow f$ almost surely when $k \rightarrow \infty$. Define now the set
$$A = \{x \in X \mid \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} f_{n_k}(x) = f(x) \ \text{exists almost surely} \ \text{and} \ f_n(x) \ \text{is increasing}\} $$
Then let $x \in A$. Then $f_{n_k}(x)$ is convergent and since $f_n(x)$is increasing we must have that
$$f_j(x) \leq f_{n_{k+j}}(x) \leq f(x) \quad \text{for all j } \in \mathbb{N}$$
where I am not sure whether the first inequality holds and if so, how would I argue for it? Because if it holds, then we know now that $f_n(x)$ is also bounded which implies that $f_n(x)$ is convergent and therefore it implies that it must have the same limit as $f_{n_k}$ such that $f_n \rightarrow f$ $\mu$-almost surely.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to proceed by your method then argue like this:-

you proceed by sandwiching the sequence $f_{n}$.

You take your almost surely convergent sequence $f_{n_{k}}(x)$ such that $f_{n_{k}}(x)\to f(x)$ for all $x\in X$ except possibly a set of $0$ measure say $B$.

Then you show that $x\in X\setminus B\implies f_{n}(x)\to f(x)$.

For each $x\in X\setminus B$ ,you find a further subsequence of $\{f_{n_{k}}(x)\}$ (call it $\{f_{n_{k_l}}(x)\}$ such that $f_{n_{k_l}}(x)\leq f_{n}(x)\leq f_{n_{k_{l+1}}}(x)$ and then let $l\to\infty$ to conclude using Sandwich Theorem that $f_{n}(x)\to f(x)$.

This proves that the sequence $f_{n}\to f\,,\forall x\in X\setminus B$ where $\mu(B)=0$.

**Alternatively**

You define $A=\{x\in X:f_{n}(x)\nrightarrow f(x)\}$.

Let $x\in A$.

Then for some $\epsilon>0$ there exists a subsequence $\{f_{m_{j}}(x)\}$ such that $f(x)-f_{m_{j}}(x)\geq \epsilon$ .

If possible let $f_{n_{k}}(x)\to f(x)$ . (This is the almost surely convergent subsequence you had taken).

Then for that particular $\epsilon$ there exists a natural number $N$ such that $k\geq N\implies f(x)-f_{n_{k}}(x)<\frac{\epsilon}{4}$ .

But we have that $f(x)-f_{m_{j}}(x)=f(x)-f_{n_{k}}(x)-(f_{m_{j}}(x)-f_{n_{k}}(x))$ . We can find a subsequence  $f_{n_{k_{s}}}(x)$ such that $f_{n_{k_{s}}}(x)\leq f_{m_{j}}(x)\leq f_{n_{k_{s+1}}}(x)$

But $f_{n_{k}}(x)$ is a Cauchy sequence and hence as $s,k\to\infty$ , $|f_{m_{j}}(x)-f_{n_{k}}(x)|\leq \min(|f_{n_{k_{s}}}(x)-f_{n_{k}}(x)|,|f_{n_{k_{s+1}}}(x)-f_{n_{k}}(x)|)\to 0$ . Hence there exists $M\in\Bbb{N}$ such that $k,j\geq M\implies |f_{m_{j}}(x)-f_{n_{k}}(x)|<\frac{\epsilon}{4} $.

Thus for $n\geq \max(N,M)$ we have

$f(x)-f_{m_{j}}(x)< \frac{\epsilon}{4}+\frac{\epsilon}{4}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ which directly contradicts that $f(x)-f_{m_j}(x)\geq \epsilon\,, \forall j\in\Bbb{N}$.

Hence $f_{n_{k}}(x)\nrightarrow f(x)\implies x\in \{x\in X: f_{n_{k}}(x)\nrightarrow f(x)\}$  .

So $A\subset \{x\in X: f_{n_{k}}(x)\nrightarrow f(x)\}$

But $\mu(\{x\in X: f_{n_{k}}(x)\nrightarrow f(x)\})=0$ by our choice of this almost surely convergent sequence . Hence $\mu(A)=0$ . Thus our sequence is almost surely convergent.

Comment: Hi, thanks. So it is not possible to make the inequality $f_j(x) \leq f_{n_{k +j}}(x) \leq f(x)$ for all $j \in \mathbb{N}$ as I did, thus concluding that since $f_n(x)$ is increasing, by assumption, and now also bounded, we know from real analysis that is in convergent and thus must converge to the same as its subsequence $f_{n_k}$ by uniqueness of the limit?

Comment: You can but $k$ will depend on $j$. Not saying that it's that much of an issue. The main argument is that as $x\in X\setminus B$(or $A$ as in your notation) then as one subsequence of this monotonic sequence converges , the entire sequence converges.  But that requires a real analysis proof and it is perhaps wise to give it. Formally you do as I did by sandwiching it. Indeed yes, if you view my method as a one sided inequality then it is the same as your method .

Answer (score 0):

There is  a subsequence ${n_k}$ such that $\mu \{x: |f_{n_k}(x)-f(x)|>\frac 1 {2^{k}}\} <\frac 1 {2^{k}}$. Thus $\sum_k \mu \{x: |f_{n_k}(x)-f(x)|>\frac 1 {2^{k}}\} <\infty$. This implies that, almost surely, $|f_{n_k}(x)-f(x)| \leq \frac 1 {2^{k}}$ for $k$ sufficiently large. Hence, $f_{n_k}$ converges to $f$ almost surely. Since $(f_n)$ is increasing it follows that $f_n$ converges to $f$ almost surely.

I have used the following:
$\sum \mu (A_n) <\infty$ implies $\mu (\lim \sup A_n)=0$ where $\lim \sup A_n$ is the set of points that belong to infinitely many of the $A_n$'s. This is proved by noting that $\lim \sup A_n =\bigcap_m \bigcup_{n\geq m} A_n \subseteq \bigcup_{n\geq m} A_n$ for each $m$.

Note: There is a simpler argument when $\mu$ is a finite measure.

Comment: My attempt is not OK?

Comment: @Mathias What do you mean your attempt is not OK? . You have not completed your proof , so how can we at all say whether it is okay or not? . If you mean that were you on the right track then yes. See my answer where I completed the proof by your idea.